# How can I assign a custom object to xarray data values?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-xarray

I have created a **DataArray** using **xarray** successfully:

```
df_invoice_features = xr.DataArray(data=None,
                                   dims={"y", "x"},
                                   coords={"y": unique_invoices, "x": cols})
```

[image]

I created a custom class and assigned one value of xarray to the instance of this class:

```
class MyArray:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.arr = np.array((s))
    def set(self, idx, val):
        self.arr[idx] = val
    def get(self):
        return self.arr

df_invoice_features.loc['basket_value_brand', invoice_id] = MyArray(len_b)
```

It is created successfully again:
[image]

But when I want to update the array of this class instance:

```
df_invoice_features.loc['basket_value_brand', invoice_id].set(0, 10)
```

It returns this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'set'
```

How can I use an array, dictionary or my custom object inside xarray data values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `df_invoice_features.loc['basket_value_brand', invoice_id]` doesn't actually return `MyArray(len_b)`. Instead, it returns an `xarray` [DataArray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html); specifically the subset of your full `DataArray` at the coordinate `['basket_value_brand', invoice_id]`. This doesn't just include the value at that location (`MyArray(len_b)`), but also all the other information stored at that `DataArray` location; i.e., your coordinates, metadata, etc.

If you want to access the actual *value* at that location, you'll have to use `.values`; i.e.,

`df_invoice_features.loc['basket_value_brand', invoice_id].values`

That should get you the `MyArray(len_b)` you're looking for. However, I'm not entirely clear what you would like to do with that class. If you're trying to change the value of your DataArray at that location, [this](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing) bit of the xarray docs in particular may be useful to review.